OnAction VBA Excel not able to call macro
I've made a vba macro to collect BoE data.
As part of my macro I have a button that removes a row of data from one sheet, alongside an entire other sheet.
    Dim btn As button
    Dim btnName As String
    Dim actionStr As String
    btnName = buttonText & "_" & sheetName ' Use sheet name for unique identifier
    Set btn = ws.Buttons.Add(ws.Cells(buttonRow, buttonColumn).Left, ws.Cells(buttonRow, buttonColumn).Top,       ws.Cells(buttonRow, buttonColumn).Width, ws.Cells(buttonRow, buttonColumn).Height)

    
    With btn
        .OnAction = "'" & buttonMacro & " """ & sheetName & """'"
        .Caption = buttonText
        .Name = btnName

This was all working perfectly fine yesterday, but today when trying to run it I get the following error:

I have literally no idea what could be causing this error at this point, and would appreciate any advice - thanks!
I've tried every possible way of writing the .OnAction line with literally no success - leading me to think the issue might lie elsewhere. Just strange given it was working yesterday

Have you read the error message? maybe the macro has been removed from the workbook (can happen if you accidentally save it as a non-macro file extension - check it is actually still there via the VBA editor) or the macros may be disabled. Check your Trust centre settings or enable macros when you open the file...

I was able to reproduce this bug systematically by doing the following: (1) Create a new workbook (2) Add a new module and paste this simplified code (3) Run CreateButton (4) Test the button to make sure it works. (5) Save and close the workbook (5) Re-open the workbook and click the button. (6) You should then see the same error message as OP. (Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2406 Build 16.0.17726.20078) 64-bit)

You do not show the whole code and it is difficult to understand where the mistake is. What is the content of buttonMacro variable? Where does the macro in discussion exist? In a standard module or in a sheet module one? Anyhow, construction "'" & buttonMacro & " """ & sheetName & """'" looks strange to me...

As mentioned in my comment, this seems like a bug. It's the first time I've seen this trick of enclosing the name of the macro and the parameter between single quotes. If you had asked me, I would have said that it's not possible to pass an argument via OnAction for a worksheet button. This technique you used is an interesting hack, but it's fragile since closing and re-opening the Excel file breaks the button.

I was able to reproduce this bug systematically by doing the following:

Create a new workbook
Add a new module and paste this simplified code
Run CreateButton
Test the button to make sure it works
Save and close the workbook
Re-open the workbook and click the button
You should then see the same error message as OP

(Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2406 Build 16.0.17726.20078) 64-bit)

A workaround would simply be to not pass any arguments, but use Application.Caller to extract the name of the sheet from the name of the button:

Sub CreateButton2()
   
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
   
    Dim Btn As Button
    Set Btn = ws.Buttons.Add(0, 0, 100, 25)
    
    With Btn
        .OnAction = "TestMacro2"
        .Caption = "Test2"
        .Name = "TestButton2_" & ws.Name
    End With

    Set Btn = Nothing

End Sub


Sub TestMacro2()

    MsgBox Right(Application.Caller, Len(Application.Caller) - InStr(Application.Caller, "_"))

End Sub


